# xml result format in notepad++ (converted from macro)

Tags: xml, macros, notepad++

I use excel macro to convert data into xml file already. It is no problem to read xml in IE, the formalt is clear. But the format has problem if open with notepad++. All the words stand in a very long line.
Is it the problem of xml heading? i guess.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

I try to open with xml notepad 2007, the format is ok. But cannot edit.
and it says:

"Your XML document contains no xml-stylesheet processing instruction. To provide an XSLT transform, add the following to the top of your file and edit the href attribute accordingly:

< ?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"? >

is it means i need to change the heading? the heading is the problem root?

Answer (score 0):

The XML stylesheet is a file you can use to display the XML in a graphical way, and you can do it using [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Css) or [XSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xsl) files.

You don't need these files to use your XML.

The header:

```
< ?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"? >
```

is useful if you want to [associate a stylesheet to your XML file](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/), not to make an XML [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling).

Also, if you cannot see the newlines chars in Notepad++, it doesn't mean that your file is not well-formed, but only that probably your macro prints the XML without an indentation process, that is useful to make your file more human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

When you use XML Notepad 2007 you edit the XML in the treeview, not in the XML output view where you would see that error message.

In the Tree View Right click on the tag *XML:Stylesheet* and select *processing instruction > Child*. this gives the option to add e.g. *type* and *href* by double clicking on the right hand side of the dividing bar where all the data is and insert e.g. *text/xml* and appropriate url for the style sheet you use.

Note however that you do not need the style sheet, as most applications including XML notepad 2007 use the default style sheet in the absence of any other specific style sheet.
The style sheet is only there to format the layout of the XML when it is displayed in a window or similar.